# Access to Microsoft Band SDK (PC and Android)

Tags: android, sdk, microsoft-band

So, I am currently embarking on a research project using multi-person physiological data and was planning to use the Microsoft Band to do so, I was quite surprised by todays message that the Band was discontinued and the SDK is no longer available.

However, as there is still considerable promise for the research project I would still like to do it and am in need of help of you fellow developers. Would anyone be so kind as to share the latest version of the SDK for PC and Android with me?

I greatly appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Luckily the Internet makes it difficult for information to be truly deleted.  You can still get to versions of the iOS and Android SDKs using [The Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160802072410/https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK).

The Windows SDK, being published with NuGet which doesn't (typically) allow removals, is still [available](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Band/).

Comment: Thank you so very much Phil! Did not knot of that Archive. You made my day! :)

Comment: You should probably also add a link to your Windows Runtime bindings [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Band.WindowsRuntime/). Particularly with [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) being official now, accessing the SDK from native code is a viable use case (even if just for me).