# How to develop windows app using sensor data of Microsoft Band even after SDK for the same is not available?

Tags: microsoft-band

I visited the developer site of Microsoft Band, it says that Microsoft Band SDK is not available, but still, I want to develop apps using Microsoft Band. So is there any method for doing the same still available.

Comment: There are archived SDK sources. Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859051/access-to-microsoft-band-sdk-pc-and-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to Microsoft Band SDK (PC and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859051/access-to-microsoft-band-sdk-pc-and-android)

Answer (score 0):

There are archived SDK sources. The answer to thus [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859051/access-to-microsoft-band-sdk-pc-and-android) contains links to the IOS and android libraries as well as the Windows SDK. It is an amazing device and it is very sad that Microsoft discontinued it.

Good luck.